Where can one see the history of huddles in a Slack channel via the Slack web UI?
Where can one see the history of huddles in a Slack channel via the Slack web UI?
I see on https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D5Hq00009NAldDKAT/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-when-a-huddle-starts-and-who-were-the-attendees?language=en_US that one may use the API, but I'd like to see the history of huddles in a Slack channel via the Slack web UI:

 Michał Kuca (ToTo)
10 months ago
Hi @Joe-20230210111512​ there is no single method for this but from huddle status event you can take 'event_ts' field https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api#callback-field and use this timestamp for https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history with 'latest' param. According to https://api.slack.com/types/conversation new response from converstations.history should hold "participant_history": ["U12345ABCDE"] field with huddle members. At least this is my understanding :)

